# REGEX: find pattern, extract data, and replace the searched pattern with a string in relations to the content of searched

Tags: regex, string, replace

As the title says, I would like to:

1) find a pattern. Ex: getting $(getThisString+100) from this string: "this is some random string $(getThisString+100)"

2) extract data. Ex: grabbing the value 100 from $(getThisString+100)

3) replace the searched pattern with a string in relations to the content of searched. Ex: replace $(getThisString+100) with 150 (100 + 50) (this 50 is any number that I just made up)

so in the end, i will need "this is some random string 150"

I'm quite new to regex, please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks a lot

Comment: you need to be a lot more specific than this. what language are you using (regex may not be the best option, and even if it is, *replace* is language-specifi). don't just say "some random string", provide specific "before" and "after" examples of expected results. provide logic/reasoning behind why 100 should be replaced with 150 (this doesn't even sound like regex; it sounds like a math operation). regex stands for *regular* expressions, not *random* expressions

Comment: I am using java for regex. I did not know programming language matters. My bad. I did provide a before after example. It's just separated lol. so it's from "this is some random string $(getThisString+100)" to ""this is some random string 150."

Comment: okay, since you feel you were being specific enough, here you go: `s/100/150/` have fun

Comment: Based on your response, I don't think it can be accomplished by regex. Thanks.

Comment: Surely `awk` can do the job, but don't know how though... http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html

Comment: I thought awk is a programming language on its own. Can I use it inside a Java environment?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
package myparser;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ParseTest {
    private final Pattern re = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\$\\(getThisString\\+(\\d+)\\)).*");

    public String parseMyString(final String str) {
        Matcher m = re.matcher(str);
        if (m.matches()) {
            int val    = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
            int newVal = val + 50;
            String strStart = str.substring(0, m.start(1));
            String strEnd   = str.substring(m.end(1));

            return parseMyString(strStart + String.valueOf(newVal) + strEnd);
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testParseNone() {
        String in = "this is some random string)";
        String out = parseMyString(in);
        assertEquals(in, out);
    }

    @Test
    public void testParseOne() {
        String in = "this is some random string $(getThisString+100)";
        String out = parseMyString(in);
        assertEquals("this is some random string 150", out);
    }

    @Test
    public void testParseMultiple() {
        String in = "this is some random string $(getThisString+100) and some more random $(getThisString+60)";
        String out = parseMyString(in);
        assertEquals("this is some random string 150 and some more random 110", out);
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- Just in case you don't know: this is a [JUnit](http://junit.org) test.
- I have used recursion to parse multiple strings. In my opinion this is a lot easier to read. When you are dealing with thousands of replacements this might lead to a stack overflow though. In that case you will have to rewrite the recursion to a loop.